# Windows HTTP GET as a web-browser

Tags: windows, http, get

**Environment:**
Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017.

**Skills**
C++ professional;
HTTP newbie;

**Problem:**
I try to access the replied html text-string from iextrading.com/apps/stocks/FDX but does not succeed.

**Tried Winsock functions**
I have try some functions gethostbyname(), htons(), connect(), send() and recv() and it works well e.g. for the site "google.com" the post "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n" works.

While for site "iextrading.com", the post "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.iextrading.com\r\n\r\n" return:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And if I try get "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: [www.iextrading.com/apps/stocks/FDX\r\n\r\n"](http://www.iextrading.com/apps/stocks/FDX%5Cr%5Cn%5Cr%5Cn%22) it say bad request.

But in any web-browser i see "iextrading.com" or "iextrading.com/apps/stocks/FDX" works fine.

**Desired:**
Is there a generic function to simply return same html-text as a web-browser does, or how to read specific this web-address "iextrading.com/apps/stocks/FDX" ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest?

Comment: Chances are that the response is telling you to redirect to a https url, which means you'll also have to build a HTTPS client. (or use an existing one)

Comment: Yes a web browser redirect to https. Does this mean I have to build with SSL, encryption and certificate ? ... It might be to high level for me. Maybe an existing.

Answer (score 1):

The host name is just that, the host name. If you want to GET "http://iextrading.com/apps/stocks/FDX" then the request URI is "/apps/stocks/FDX", not "/".

Comment: This issue still remain. I do not get reply or a new link, just Permanent Removed. So I still cannot get reply as a web-browser get :( . But much thanks for the other info :)  If I apply "GET /apps/stocks/FDX HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.iextrading.com\r\n\r\n" I get Permanent Removed and not Bad request.

Comment: Read the spec. The server is redirecting you to another resource.